# Sockets: measure elapsed time since the last message

Tags: c++, sockets

I have multiple clients sending messages to a server. I'm trying to detect the situation, when there are no new messages for more than 5 seconds. Here is my code (I removed a lot of lines that are not relevant):

```
listen(sockfd, 5000);
time_t new_msg;
time(&new_msg);

while (true) {
    time_t current;
    time(&current);
    //if more than 5 seconds passed since the last message:
    if (difftime(current, new_msg) > 5) { 
    //do something
    }

    client = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (client < 0) {
        cout << "Error on accepting" << endl;
        continue;
    }
    n = read(client, buffer, read_len - 1);
    if (n < 0) cout << "Error on reading from the socket" << endl;
    else if (n == 0) continue;

    time(&new_msg); //save time for the last message
    //if everything is ok, do something with the message
}
```

The problem is that after the last message (when the break starts), the difference between the current time and the last message's time is checked only once and equals 0 seconds. Then the server seems to just wait for messages in this line:

```
client = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
```

How can I check the time again? Or is there any simplier way to check for how long the server is idle?

**Update:**

I created the following loop before `accept`:

```
do {
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &readfds);
    res = select(maxfd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    time_t waiting;
    time(&waiting);
    if (difftime(waiting, current) >= 5) {
        //do something
    }
} while (res < 0);
```

It doesn't look very clean, but at least works.

Comment: Does it ever print the "Error on accepting" ?

Comment: @farbiondriven no, it never does, it just waits

Comment: I even tried to print something between `accept` and `if (client < 0)`, and it's not printed in case there are no new messages.

Comment: Yeah I think the accept function is currently synchronous. I'm looking for an async version, this is what you're looking for !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
listen(sockfd, 5000);
time_t new_msg;
time(&new_msg);

while (true) {
    time_t current;
    ...
```

Another possibility would be to use `select()` or `poll()` instead of `accept()`.

Comment: `fcntl` works, but the system freezes after a few seconds, no idea why.

`select()` seems to work, but I'm trying to figure out how to use it in a simple way, without maintaining the list of readfds. I have several lists for different kinds of clients, so it would be a bit complicated..

Comment: So, I tried to make a loop with select with a timer (will add the code to the post) and measure the time there. Looks kinda dirty, but it works. :)
Thank you!